# jquery: animate $('id1').before('some html') to fadeIn and from red to transparent

Tags: jquery

I want to make something just like on this site (when you/or somebody else adds an answer)

the answer appears and fades in and comes from orange to transparent, anybody knows how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) and animate the background color of whatever element you want, like this:

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);
```

This will fade it from whatever color you set it to initially (or via [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) just before the animate) to the color you specify over 1 second.  [You can try the other color plugin demos here](http://dev.jquery.com/~john/ticket/fx-rewrite2/).

Comment: It worked for me without adding the color plugin, probably because I have jquery UI added